# merging two accounts on math.stackexchange

Tags: support, merge-accounts

---

I would like to merge two accounts on math.stackexchage, once with open ID : [old acount](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/98773/mounaim)
and the second is the one I'm connecting with now.

How can I do this ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) :)

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) is a place on the math site just for this. It is probably better to contact the community team for math.stackexchange.com than for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I've already found the link : http://math.stackexchange.com/contact , i choosed the merge accounts option.